# Did I ever! -- what does this emphatic statement exactly mean when you say it?

Tags: colloquial-language, exclamatives

Example:

> — Did you see how Bill came in to work this morning?
>   — **Did I ever!** Boy, was he hot under the collar!
>   — What brought that on?
>   — He said that he was extremely angry because he got stuck in slow-moving traffic and arrived late for an important business meeting.

What does this emphatic statement exactly mean and how to use it? Please, explain the grammar behind it. And also proving some more examples would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It means that the speaker of "Did I ever!" actually did see Bill come in that morning, and actually did notice that Bill was mad  (that is, "hot under the collar"). That is, the speaker really, really, did notice that Bill was real mad that morning.

Comment: [do/is/can etc. someone ever](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/ever) "(spoken) used for emphasizing that someone does something or has a particular quality"

Comment: So, basically the speaker says that he really saw him and also how angry he was. Right?

Comment: Right. :) . . . That is, in this context, that's what it means.

Comment: I missed it. This is ***entirely*** new thing for me. Not just +1 but favorited for further reference. Thanks for asking. It helped me a lot1

Comment: @DamkerngT. I checked the entry. Don't you think it **must** require a question mark? In fact, when we speak, we speak like a question - *Did I ever? over Did I ever!* In fact, the 'exclamatory mark' was the primary cause of my misunderstanding.

Comment: @MaulikV I think the examples in the dictionary make it clear enough.

Comment: @DamkerngT. still need some clarity. Never mind, I do homework! :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This form of sentence is what is sometimes called an inverted exclamative. Exclamatives are used not only to show that the speaker thinks that something is true, but that they find it *very relevant* or *very interesting*. Often they highlight one particular aspect of the sentence. Here are three different types of exclamative sentence:

- Boy, was I ever hungry. (inverted exclamative)
- How hungry I was. (*Wh*-exclamative)
- I was so hungry. (*So*-exclamative)

We can also mix up these different types of exclamative:

- How hungry was I? (inverted *wh* exclamative).

In the examples above, the aspect of the sentence that is being highlighted is the hunger. In other words the sentence is saying that the speaker thinks that the extent of his hunger is particularly relevant or particularly interesting.

Sometimes we can miss out a part of the sentence and just use an auxiliary verb:

- Boy, did I ever!
- Boy, have I ever!
- Boy, would I ever!

Notice that the *ever* part of these sentences is optional, but it increases the exclamative effect. We really understand that the speaker finds this thing very relevant or significant. In the Original Poster's example the speaker is saying that the way that Bob came in, or how he was when he came in is very interesting or significant:

> — Did you see how Bill came in to work this morning?
>   — **Did I ever!** Boy, was he hot under the collar!

Notice that the last sentence has *two* inverted exclamatives. These both have the same shape as a question: *Did I ever?* and *Was he hot under the collar?*. (Inverted exclamatives are sometimes called "interrogative" exclamatives for this reason.)

We can use these types of exclamation in speech and very informal writing when we want to tell our listener or reader that we find something extremely relevant, surprising or significant - and we want them to find it relevant too.

- Boy! How so very interesting was  *that* question! (inverted *wh* so-exclamative!)

Hope this is helpful!

[**Potentially boring but significant note**: Many grammarians (and not-yet grammarians like me!) try to categorise clauses in two ways. One according to the syntax, another according to the function. The clauses that I call *exclamative*, here, I call exclamative because of their *illocutionary function*. These clauses still have some specific syntactic features. They certainly have very special intonational features. It may, however, be important to note that the structure of these sentences may be the same as different "syntactic" types of clause: *declarative, interrogative* and *exclamative*.]

Comment: +1, nice post. But you might want to be aware that the 2002 *CGEL* considers *exclamative* as a major clause type, and that much of what you discussed happened to concern non-exclamative *exclamations* (this according to their grammar framework). :)

Comment: @F.E. Thanks! Yes, I thought about trying to work that in ... but ... erm, guess I was feeling more old school and functional than modern and syntactic etc. Have tried to do an address without getting too terminological .. Don't know, might have made it worse. Am trying to not do any posts at the mo! (yes, am failing...). If you did more that might help! ;) I could just get some good reading as a break :)

Answer (score 4):

It means, "Emphatically **YES**!!"  Because of the repetition of the verb "did", it's mostly only used when the question also includes "did".

Intonation and punctuation are important.  If somebody asks, "Did it rain yesterday?" and you answer excitedly "Did it ever!", you mean "Wow, it rained a huge amount yesterday."  If you answer in a dull tone, "Did it ever?", you're suggesting that it hasn't rained for a long time by hyperbolically asking if it's rained ever in history.

Comment: Hmmm, we seem to be able to use many auxiliaries here. Not just *DO*.

Comment: @Araucaria I agree but the question was asking about "Did I ever!"  You might answer "Are you happy?" with "Am I ever!" but you wouldn't answer it with "Did I ever!"

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood! :)